# What is the green download icon in the Mac menu bar?

Tags: icon, menu-bar

I've done a reverse image search and come up with nothing. The icon is not clickable and I find nothing in the StartupItems folders or in the Login Items in the control panel. Can anyone tell me what this icon is for?

[image: Mystery icon]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As per this [Apple Community answer](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/7189321) on a similar question:

> That is the LibreOffice/OpenOffice indicator that shows that an update is available, and it is on the Finder menu bar, not in Safari.